# Vue component return value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to VUE and am trying to clean up my code by creating components instead of repeating code.

How do you return a varform a child component?

**Main.vue**

```
<template>
     <square value="5" @click="result"></square>
</template>
```

**Square.vue**

```
[...]
mounted() {
     return { fromSquare: value*value } 
}
```

**Main.vue**

```
methods: {
   result(fromSquare) {
       this.squaredResult = fromSquare;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to emit an event from `square` component with `value*value` as payload and add its handler in parent :

```
mounted() {
    this.$emit("emit-result",value*value)
}
```

**Main.vue**

```
<template>
     <square value="5" @click="result" @emit-result="result"></square>
</template>

....

methods: {
   result(fromSquare) {
       this.squaredResult = fromSquare;
   }

}
```